# overriding virtual function differs in DLL generated project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am working on a Visual studio project

```
header.h
class A
{
  virtual int __cdecl  funct1() = 0;
};
```

Project B(which generates a DLL on compilation)

```
 //projectBheader.h
#include<header.h>
#define projectBclass_DLL __declspec( dllexport )
class projectBclass_DLL projectBclass: public A
{
  virtual int __cdecl funct1();
}

//projectBheader.cpp

A::int __cdecl  projectBclass::funct1()
{
  //definition goes here
}
```

but it is giving error

```
error C2695: 'projectBclass::funct1': overriding virtual function differs 
from 'A::funct1' only by calling convention
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "differs only by calling convention" suggests that the __stdcall/__cdecl/etc specifiers do not match. If that space is really in your header, that could be it, as "int__cdecl" would hide the cdecl and the compiler might have complained about "__cdecl" missing. However, if it is not that - then be sure to doule or triple check if the __cdecl is really understood as callingconvention marker. It might be i.e. substituted to "" by some #define etc.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl that is a typing error which is now corrected

Comment: Probably it wants you to mark class A as `__declspec( dllexport )` too.

Comment: What is A::int doing there? class A does not define a type called "int".

Answer (score 1):

#### Short version:

Maybe you have to use `public` access modifiers.

#### Long version:

Just a wild guess, but maybe you have got an accessibility problem, not a calling convention problem. I was surprised to see that one can export private class members, but maybe you cannot after all? (please correct me if I am wrong)

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), "To export all of the **public** data members and member functions in a class, the keyword must appear to the left of the class name ..." as you did.
The default scope is private, though.